# Position representation of product of two operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

If two operators $\hat{a},\hat{b}$ have their position representations as $a, b$ ( both $a, b$ are operators but here they act on wavefunctions rather than kets) then is it true in general that the operator $\hat{a}\hat{b}$ , which is a product of the two operators  has its position representation as the product of the position representation of the individual operators i.e is the position representation of $\hat{a}\hat{b}$ given as $a b$ ?

Comment: This reads like a homework question and we do not solve those. What are your thoughts on this? Have you tried solving it? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, a representation is supposed to obey the same rules of algebra.

Comment: @Infintezero,I'll update my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Let the wavefunction of $|\psi\rangle$ be $\psi (x)$

Let $a, b$ be the position representation of $A, B$.

Then we've $b \psi (x)= 
 \langle x | B|\psi\rangle$ .

Let $f(x)=\langle x | B|\psi\rangle$ be wavefunction of $|f\rangle$

Then we've $a f (x)= 
 \langle x | A|f\rangle$

Then $\begin{aligned} a b \psi(x) &=a\langle x|\hat{B}| \psi\rangle=a f(x) \\ &=\langle x|\hat{A}| f\rangle \\=\langle x|\hat{A}| \hat{B} \mid \psi\rangle \end{aligned}$